# Eloquent get value Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

This is my Vote model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vote extends Model
{
    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function options(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Option');
    }
}
```

this is my Option model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Option extends Model
{
    public function vote(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Vote');
    }

    public function users(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

The case is i want to get the users data from many to many relationship in Option model, but started from Vote model. So i get the options data in the Vote model first, then i get the users data in Option model (many to many)

Comment: You want a direct relationship from `Vote` to `User`?

Comment: yap, but i don't know how @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```
class Vote extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(User::class, [Option::class, 'option_user']);
    }
}
```